# How to manually set button input type in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I have a jQueryUI dialog with some textboxes, plus a button. Right now, the `asp:Button` tag used to generate the button automatically sets its type as `type="submit"`. The structure of the dialog is such that pressing enter at any of the textboxes should not call the button click event. It seems like the cleanest way to solve the problem, if it is doable, is to manually set the button's type to something other than `submit`. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: Forgot to mention this, but the button text is bound to a database item by `<%# Eval() %>`, which doesn't work without a server-side tag.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

" 
        UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
        OnClientClick="return" />

The [UseSubmitBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx) property tells ASP.NET to render as `type="button"` and inserts a `__doPostBack()` function call into the `onclick` property.  The text of the [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property gets prepended to the client-side `onclick` event (with a trailing semicolon if you don't include it yourself), therefore putting `return` simply short-circuits the event handler and ends up doing nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can use just a regular html button and set it to whatever you want.  It doesn't have to be a serverside asp button.

In your aspx file:

```
<input type="button" value="My Button" onclick="DoSomeScript();" />
```

Comment: What about when the button's value depends on an Eval()?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the Button control's `AutoPostBack` to false, which would normally do what you want.

In this case, I would simply not use `asp:Button` and just use `<input type='button'>`.